# Get page title and link of parent CMS page in CMS Hierarchy

Tags: magento-enterprise, cms, navigation, page-title

Is there a good method for retrieving the page title and url of the parent CMS page when using Magento's CMS Hierarchy?

Example Structure:

- About Us

  - Culture
  - Contact

I need to be able to get the About Us page title on Culture and Contact pages.

The only method I've come up with is this terrible code which grabs the parent page's title:

```
<?php echo ($_tree[0][3]->getData("page_title")); ?>
```

Right now it's showing the current page title instead of the parent page title: http://grab.by/Drl4 as I'm using the code:

```
<?php echo str_replace(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_prefix'), '', $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle()); ?>
```

Any ideas of a reusable and clean method to grab the parent CMS page's title and url?

side note : I have [magento-enterprice](/questions/tagged/magento-enterprice) editition with me.

Comment: There is no CMS page hierarchy in CE/EE, are you using Go or an extension?

Comment: No extension. It's Magento Enterprise's Hierarchy: http://grab.by/Droc

Comment: You would think I'd actually check first, yep I see it under content management (shows how much I use that particular setting!)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for you:

```
if ($currentNode = Mage::registry('current_cms_hierarchy_node')) {
    // Zend_Debug::dump($currentNode->getData());
    $parentId       = $currentNode->getParentNodeId();
    $parentNode  = Mage::getModel('enterprise_cms/hierarchy_node')
        ->load($parentId);
    // Zend_Debug::dump($parentNode->getData());

    $parentTitle    = $parentNode->getPageTitle();
    $parentUrl      = Mage::getUrl($parentNode->getRequestUrl());
    // Zend_Debug::dump($parentTitle);
    // Zend_Debug::dump($parentUrl);
}
```

You can run this code from any .phtml file.

Comment: Don't you think your commented out code is a bit superfluous for the answer?  (Not to mention using a deprecated commenting method...)